# Background timer for react-native ios

Tags: ios, react-native

I need to restrict one my functionality with a timer. So I am using [react-native-background-timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) plugin for that. In case of android, its working fine and I am getting my expected output. But in case of IOS it working only when app is in foreground, when I press home button after 4-5 seconds this plugin timer also gets paused. I have followed all instructions mentioned in this plugin. Still no luck.

Here is my code:-

```
BackgroundTimer.start();
setInterval(() => {
       // Here I am writing my business logic
       //Which works properly in case of foreground.
   }, 1000)
```

I am also [added comment](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer/issues/111#issuecomment-458547299) here to get implementation help.

Please let me know. Is I am doing anything wrong?

Also suggest any alternatives for my functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned plugin is wroking fine, because it's using **dispatchAsync method** which is basically using in IOS to do small background work.

Check **Usage Crossplatform** section.

```
BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(() => { 
console.log("Background Timer");
//Check above log will appear after every 3 seconds.
//Your timer reducing and updating code goes here 
}, 
3000);

//Don't forget to remove Timer
//rest of code will be performing for iOS on background too
BackgroundTimer.stopBackgroundTimer();
```